Is it possible to add more than two extra ledgers in Standard Music Font Layout (SMuFL)?
As per the W3C page, you can add 8 lower/raise positions, which should account for two extra ledger lines (starting from the middle line in a 5-line staff). In many cases, this is not enough.
So, for example, using 'Bravura' (the default SMuFL font), and the following Unicode values:
U+E014 U+EB9D U+E022 U+EB9F U+E022 U+EB9F U+EBA4
renders just two extra ledgers:

Is there a way to add more than two ledger lines + notes, in SMuFL? For example:

I have already tried combining two positions (e.g., U+EB98 and U+EB9F), but only the rightmost (i.e., the one closest to the note/staff) Unicode seems to be applied.
Thanks.
